# Checking folder is exist or not in QT

Tags: qt, directory

I am learning/looking QT. When I want to reach a folder or file, it is exist or not, program always return folder is not exist (NO).

```
QDir myDir("D:\try");   //I created try folder under D disk.
if (myDir.exists())
{
    qDebug("YES");
}
else
{
    qDebug("NO");
}
```

Comment: `QDir myDir("D:\try");` do not create any folder

Comment: Try ”D:\\try” path. I think it will be all right!

Answer (score 0):

The '\t' in "D:\try" is interpreted as a tab character by the compiler.  And the path "D:    try" presumably does not exist.

It's often useful in these kind of tests to print out the string you are using in the debug statement, rather than just the success/fail message, so you can validate that the input is actually what you expect.